# What is the chance of Skatole to appear at the Shell Game?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

In the Arcade room when you play the Shell Game with the beggar there is a chance of him revealing Skatole under one of the Host Skulls when betting.

I know when it appears you have a 33% chance of winning (nearly 55% when having Lucky Foot) but the chance of it appearing is not stated anywhere.

Is it completely random or is there a set chance percentage of it appearing? Or is it based on your Luck stat?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd like to say that the chance of winning is probably nowhere near 33% — drop rates seem to favor the resources you have the most of — but without running numbers it's probably comfirmation bias. Also the [Luck stat](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Stats/Hidden_Stats#Luck) is only believed to affect end-of-room drops.

Comment: @badp It should be a 1 in 3 chance of winning. It also says 33% on the wiki. Not sure how trustworthy that is but still.

Comment: @badp it would be 33% chance to select the correct skull, but not to have the beggar offer the Skat as a prize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [mechanics guide](https://gist.github.com/dpatti/4419061#skull-game), the chances of revealing Skatole is **1/13**.